# Select2 Templating <span>text</span> in selection render

Tags: javascript, html, select, jquery-select2

I've got stacked on select stylization. I'm not so pro, im just learning and I cant solve this problem alone yet. 
I use select2 and found the most acceptable type for select form. I tried to understand what is going wrong but I couldn't. I want such select which show span with text, not just a text. Like its on pic#1. But i all the time get  only text without color mark - pic#2.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDFEv.jpg)

My code is:

```
<div class="fieldset fieldset-1">
   <label for="color">Choose color</label>
   <select name="color" class="color-choose">                             
      <option value="grn">Green</option>
      <option value="blu">Blue</option>
      <option value="brn">Brown</option>
      <option value="blk">Black</option>
      <option value="red">Red</option>
      <option value="yel">Yellow</option>
      <option value="wht">White</option>                                  
    </select>
 </div>
```

and JS code:

```
function formatState (state) {
  if (!state.id) { return state.text; }
  var $state = $(
    '<span class="color-element color-' + state.element.value + '">' + state.text + '</span>'
  );
  return $state;
};

$(".color-choose").select2({
  templateResult: formatState
});
```

so i got such result:  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyhi1.jpg)

Please, help me to solve it! Will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only setting the template for the results (using `templateResult`), but you are not setting the template for the selection. Select2 allows you to use different templates for selections and results (see [the AJAX example](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax)), so you must set the renderer for selections using the `templateSelection` option.

```
$(".color-choose").select2({
  templateResult: formatState,
  templateSelection: formatState
});
```